# Editing a deleted answer

Tags: bug, status-completed, edits, deleted-answers

I'm trying to edit **my** answer that I've deleted.

Clicking on "edit" link takes me to the "Edit" page, and I can actually edit my answer and click "Save Your Edits" button if I do it **fast enough**.

However, if I start editing the answer but don't save it within about 30 seconds to a minute, "Save Your Edits" is disabled and "This post has been deleted - no more edits are allowed" message is shown on top.

**Update**: Actually, I've just tested and it happens when editing **any** deleted answer; whether it was mine or someone else's.

Comment: Yes, but it shouldn't be doing the notification if you are editing your own answer.  It arguably should be when editing someone else's.

Comment: @tvanfosson - why? I should be notified if someone's answer is deleted **after** I started editing it, but that's not what happens. I'm editing an **already** deleted answer when the behavior described above occurs.

Comment: I didn't realize the system allowed people to edit other people's deleted answers.  What would be the point in that?  Shouldn't someone else's answer have to be reopened before it can be edited?

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure what's the point in editing someone else's deleted answer - but the feature is there, it just doesn't work as well as it could have :-)

Answer (score 4):

I noticed this as well.  It seems that the notification mechanism isn't playing well with the edit your own deleted post feature.

Answer (score 4):

I noticed this today.

I think you *should* be able to edit at least *your own* deleted answer.

If I notice a major *faux pas* which requires more than a quick edit-fix-save, I delete the post, refactor relentlessly, and undelete. Can't do that now.

Comment: You can - sort of :-) Delete it, click on "edit", refactor as needed, ignore the "can't save message", copy your changes, go back, click "edit" again, paste your changes, click "save", profit!

Comment: And +1, I definitely agree that you should be able to edit your deleted answer; this was added recently and it's a nice feature.

Comment: Yup. That would work but... yeesh.