# Error while editing Deleted Post: This post has been deleted - no more edits are allowed

Tags: bug, status-completed, edits, deleted-answers

There's a [similar post here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6347/let-me-edit-my-own-deleted-post) but I think my situation is slightly different.

I deleted an answer I posted in SO, after realising I've misread the question. So I proceed to edit the deleted post so as to fit the question better, without getting down-voted :P

After about a minute into the edit, the top bar dropped this message: **This post has been deleted - no more edits are allowed**

[image: This post has been deleted - no more edits are allowed]

I thought the OP was deleted and check it out. It wasn't. So I tried again and the same thing happened.

However I am still able to perform the edit the third time round because I've copy-and-paste-and-post again within 15 seconds.

Is there something about this I do not know? I'm trying to persuade myself this is not a bug.

**EDIT:**

The "Save Your Edits" button will be disabled after the prompt bar dropped down:
[image: Save Your Edits]

Comment: This happened to me as well; very strange, very annoying!

Comment: Dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30250/editing-a-deleted-answer.  Marked as status-planned.

Comment: @tvanfosson: Thanks, hope it'll be implemented soon. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will appear when you're inside the window of polling to alert you and others about the changed state of the post.

It's similar to the bar that pops up when you edit a post and then go and edit it again to fix up something you didn't catch first edit around.

So like in this similar situation:

- Post, then notice a spelling error
- Edit to fix spelling error
- Save the edit, then realise the spelling error now leaves a tragedy of grammatical proportions
- Edit to fix grammar
- While in edit mode, told that the post has been edited.

But then you find out you were the one all along.

Same polling and notification here for the deleted post.

Comment: It's a little confusing, in my opinion. If I'm editing something that I deleted, why on earth would I be told that the post has been deleted (it's obvious, I did it, I don't suffer from amnesia) and why would I be told I can't edit it any more (I'm already editing it, why am I allowed there in the first place?).

Comment: Well, being told "the post is edited" is one thing, while "post has been deleted" is another. The "Save Your Edits" button is disabled and I'm 'stucked'.

Comment: Are you saying you don't like exercises in frustration?

Comment: @Random: exercises? You mean the race against the clock to complete editing before the error bar drops?

Comment: I exercise in frustration every day!

Answer (score 7):

If I'm not allowed to edit something, just grey out the edit link and that's that. Why should I be allowed to enter edit mode when I'm not allowed to edit? This turns it into an exercise in frustration; I go in, I edit the post, yet I'm not allowed to submit the changes. This thing tells me: *Yes, you can edit the post, but no, you can't actually edit this post*.

Either let us:

- edit out own deleted posts (which is the **right behavior**, maybe I just misread the question and now I want to fix my mistakes while not being downvoted like crazy) or
- not allow us to enter into edit mode **at all** if it's been deleted.

Comment: The thing is, we are allowed to edit, just have to do it within seconds. :P

Comment: That changes anything. Start the clock, then!