# I shouldn't or should be able to edit a deleted answer, but not both

Tags: bug, status-declined, edits

There seems to be [a similar bug report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31548/error-while-editing-deleted-post-this-post-has-been-deleted-no-more-edits-are) about *one's own answers*.
This is is about editing *someone else's answers*. Also, the other post has been marked as completed, which is certainly isn't!

---

*This only applies to 10k users.*

### The bug

Deleted questions still have an `edit` button. By pressing it the normal edit window opens and one starts editing. But after a short time, presumably through an AJAX call, a banner opens with the caption *This post has been deleted - no more edits are allowed* and the *Save your Edits* button gets disabled.

Still, if I'm quick enough to edit the post and press the button, before the banner shows up I'm able to edit the question.

### The solution

The correct behaviour would either be:

- Don't allow me to edit deleted posts.

  - Still let me edit my own deleted posts.

or

- Allow me to edit those posts, but don't show that banner.

### Observations

- What about community-deleted posts, should 10k users be able to edit them?
- I should be able to edit my own posts when I've deleted them myself.

Comment: So what exactly has been declined?

Comment: @Mmyers I believe it was the bug-fix that was declined. This only applies to a small subset of users, and they shouldn't be doing this anyway. Presumably, they're unwilling to devote the time to fixing it.