# "This post has been deleted - no more edits are allowed" when editing own Roomba'd question

Tags: bug, edits, deleted-questions, notification-bar

While editing [one of my questions which got Roomba'd](https://stackapps.com/q/8039/34061), I got a "This post has been deleted - no more edits are allowed" banner, and the 'Save Edits' button was disabled:

[image: edit page showing "This post has been deleted - no more edits are allowed" banner]

As mentioned [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30250/editing-a-deleted-answer#comment64433_30260), I could copy the content, go back and edit the question again; this time I didn't see the banner and I was able to submit the edit. But both that bug and [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/31548/295232) have been marked [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) in 2009.

Comment: Go to Inspect Element and remove `disabled="disabled"`. Then you can edit it.

Comment: That's a nice trick, I'll be sure to try it next time. I'm going to rollback your edit, [regression] is not a relevant tag and will be burninated.